# bitwise operation to extract each individual word from a long

Tags: java, c++, c, bit-manipulation

I have a `long` that corresponds to an assembly language instruction.
Here's the problem; the first field is Opcode. It can be either 1 or 2 digits. So for example in `120602`, 12 is the opcode. In `10602`, 1 is the opcode.

I want to extract each individual field; where opcode is the first 1-2 numbers on the left, 1 to the right of that is op1mode, 1 to the right of that is op1gpr, 1 to the right of that is op2mode, and finally, the last part is op2gpr.
Ideally, I want to assign each to its own variable for later use, or separate them in an array.

I was thinking that this can be achievable using bitwise operations; namely masks and shifts.

How would one split the number with just bitwise operations?

Comment: Are you sure these opcodes should be parsed as decimals? This is usually done in hex, in all the assembly languages I know: Z80, 8x86, MC68000, ARM3. (I've also written disassemblers for all of these.)

Comment: this is actually for school, and we are using a hypothetical decimal system which parses it as decimals

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise/bitshifts won't do you any good unless the fields are combined in a base 2 representation. As shown, your digits are base 10. On the other hand, you can use integer division and modulo for the numbers you've shown.

```
120602 / 10000 = 12
120602 % 10000 = 602
```

These basically correspond to the following types of operations for binary digits:

```
0x1D71A >>> 12 = 0x1D
0x1D71A & 0xFFF = 0x71A
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do that (*but without bit manipulation*), is to define an array containing five integers, and then to fill it which the digits of your number. You will have to **begin from the end of the number**, it is easier.

**An example in Java:**

```java
long number = 120602;
int[] op = new int[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    op[i] = (int) (number % 10);
    number /= 10;
}
op[4] = (int) number;
```

---

And here:

- `op[0]` is *op2gpr*
- `op[1]` is *op2mode*
- `op[2]` is *op1gpr*
- `op[3]` is *op1mode*
- `op[4]` is *opcode*